# How to trim space between two delimiters - Unix

Tags: text-processing

In a file we have key and value pairs separated by |, my request is to remove space in key pair as shown in Input and Output.
Example:
UTC Time Offset -> UTCTimeOffset

I have tried different sed and awk commands but unable to get the right commands

Input:

```
LogID = AMQ11111.0.FDC|Date/Time = Wed April 14 2021 03:19:43 EET|UTC Time = 1618334334.03|UTC Time Offset = 660 (EFT)|
```

Output:

```
LogID = AMQ11111.0.FDC|Date/Time = Wed April 14 2021 03:19:43 EET|UTCTime = 1618334334.03|UTCTimeOffset = 660 (EFT)|
```

Comment: Are you really using Unix or did you mean Linux?

Comment: using both linux and Aix

Comment: Do you have `perl` installed on your AIX?

Comment: No terdon, cant we do it with sed or awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that no key or value contains embedded `|` or `=` characters:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = RS = "|"; OFS = FS = " =" }{ gsub(" ", "", $1) }; NF > 1' file
```

This treats the input as a set of `|`-delimited records.  Each record uses  `=` (space+`=`) as the field delimiter.

For each record, the spaces in the first field (your keys) are deleted using `gsub()`.  If the current record has more than a single field, it is then printed (this is tested to avoid outputting an empty record at the end).

There is no newline at the end of the output.

I'm unfortunately unable to test this on AIX, but I don't think it uses any non-standard `awk` features.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou very much. Working!!

Comment: It doesn't use any non-standard features but it does produce output that isn;t a valid POSIX text file due to having no terminating newline as you mentioned so YMMV with what any subsequent tool might do with it and it would fail if any of the values contains `=` (e.g. `...| Foo = "this = that" | ...`) as well as the `|` you mentioned.

Comment: @EdMorton Any `awk` program that sets `ORS` to something other than `\n` would suffer from the same "issue" unless an explicit newline is produced at the end. In this case, it would be easy to use `END { printf "\n" }` or combine the output with `echo` in the calling shell if this needed to be addressed at all.

Comment: That's correct, adding `END{printf "\n"}` would solve the problem as long as you don't mind a single newline being output if the input file was empty. I wouldn't add a call to `echo`.

Comment: As a simple example of when this would matter, imagine the OP running `wc -l` on the output to see how many lines were printed. Without that trailing newline the resulting count will be `0` instead of `1` given the OPs sample input. If you add `END{print "\n"}` then for an empty file (or any other case where no lines match the conditions that cause a print) the result would be `1` instead of `0`. It's better to just ensure output, if any, ends in a newline to avoid any potentially confusing (or portability) issues.

Comment: @EdMorton In this case, it is made clear in the text that there is no newline at the end of the output.  So there is no confusion.

Comment: @Kusalananda my comment is for the benefit of the many people posting questions or browsing on this forum who have no idea what the implications of not having a newline at the end of the output are. If you changed your comment to say `There is no newline at the end of the output and so YMMV with what any other tool might do with the output" or similar then I'd be happy to remove my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on any Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        key = val = $i
        sub(/ *=.*/,"",key)
        sub(/[^=]*= */,"",val)
        gsub(/ /,"",key)
        $i = key " = " val
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
LogID = AMQ11111.0.FDC|Date/Time = Wed April 14 2021 03:19:43 EET|UTCTime = 1618334334.03|UTCTimeOffset = 660 (EFT)|
```

The above assumes that none of your fields can contain `|` and that each line ends with `|`.